# React Native Scrollview Stop Momentum? (expo)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using a [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html), and when I scroll and let go, it keeps scrolling because of momentum. I want it to only scroll when the finger is touching the screen, I do not want the momentum. Is this possible, if so, how?

Comment: Set ```decelerationRate``` to ```"fast"```. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#decelerationrate

Comment: this is IOS only

Comment: any luck with this 8 months later?

Answer (score 2):

Using `decelerationRate` prop with value `0` can help.

Based on [the document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#decelerationrate), its value accept string `normal | fast` and floating number from `0` to `1` orderly from slowest to fastest.

```
<ScrollView decelerationRate={0}>

</ScrollView>
```

** I am using RN v0.59 **

Answer (score 2):

Add 2 following properties to `ScrollView`:

```
snapToInterval={1}
disableIntervalMomentum={true}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not try this (RN 0.55)

```
<ScrollView 
  ref={r => (this.scrollView = r)}
  onScrollEndDrag={e => {
    return this.scrollView.scrollTo({ y: e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y });
  }}>
  ...
</ScrollView>
```