# React native - scroll by snapToInterval in scrollview

Tags: react-native, scrollview

Sort question: How do I ensure that each scroll has as scroll as the value I specified in the snapToInterval.

Detail: No matter how fast I scroll when scrolling in scrollview, how can I make it scroll as much as the snapToInterval value. I've attached a video link below.

[Video Url](https://ysnv.vercel.app/?videoUrl=https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/508056984541462533/784949608085717052/222o.mp4)

What I want is to scroll 1 video each time I scroll no matter how fast I scroll. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55254957/10039122), but that doesn't exactly solve my problem.

my code:

```
<FlatList
  data={videos}
  decelerationRate={0}
  keyExtractor={i => i.id}
  snapToInterval={videoHeight + 16}
  renderItem={({ index, item: { id: videoId } }) => (
    <YouTubePlayer
      key={videoId}
      videoId={videoId}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<FlatList
data={videos}
decelerationRate={0}
keyExtractor={i => i.id}
renderItem={({ index, item: { id: videoId } }) => (
<YouTubePlayer
  key={videoId}
  videoId={videoId}
/>
)}
snapToInterval={Dimensions.get('window').height}
snapToAlignment={'start'}
decelerationRate={'fast'}
/>
```